# how can i display my nested array in another table angular

Tags: arrays, angular, angular-material, nested

i want my nested json array 'orderdetials' to be displayed in another table dialog component , how can i do so?
here is a picture on how it should look [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvS4D.png)

i want only orderdetials to be displayed in another table when i click the button on each row as displayed in the picture

here is my .json

```
 "OrderList": [
    {
      "id": "4",
      "operationType": "retail",
      "date": "2022-11-21T21:00:00.000Z",
      "address": "Romnia",
      "custname": "Omar",
      "nettotal": 234,
      "grosstotal": 987,
      "totaltax": 0.008,
      "totaldiscount": 0.034,
      "quantityTotal": 700,
      "orderdetials": [
        {
          "idd": "razor",
          "price": 70,
          "quantity": 3,
          "discount": 0.06,
          "tax": 0.03,
          "total": 1000
        }
```

i tried *ngfor but it didnt work .

here is my .html:

```
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
  
      <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> ID. </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.id}} </td>
      </ng-container> 
    
      <ng-container matColumnDef="date">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header > Date </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.date | date}} </td>
      </ng-container>
    
      <ng-container matColumnDef="address">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Address </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.address}} </td>
      </ng-container>
    
      <ng-container matColumnDef="custname">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Cust-Name </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.custname}} </td>
      </ng-container>
    
      <ng-container matColumnDef="nettotal">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Net-Total </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.nettotal | currency}} </td>
      </ng-container>
    
      <ng-container matColumnDef="grosstotal">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Gross-Total </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.grosstotal | currency}} </td>
      </ng-container>
    
      <ng-container matColumnDef="totaltax">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Total-tax </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.totaltax | percent}} </td>
      </ng-container>
    
      <ng-container matColumnDef="totaldiscount">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Total-Discount </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.totaldiscount | percent}} </td>
      </ng-container>
    
      <ng-container matColumnDef="operationType" >
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Operation-Type </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.operationType}} </td>
      </ng-container>
  
      <ng-container matColumnDef="quantityTotal" >
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Quantity Total </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.quantityTotal + ' Items'}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- <ng-container matColumnDef="orderdetials">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> detials </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" *ngIf="">  </td>
      </ng-container> -->
    
      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
    
      <tr class="mat-row" *matNoDataRow>
        <td class="mat-cell" colspan="4">No data matching the filter "{{input.value}}"</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

.ts :

```
export interface PeriodicElement {
  id : number;
  date : string;
  address : string;
  custname : string ;
  netTotal : number;
  grossTotal : number;
  Totaltax : number;
  totaldiscount : number;
  operationType : string;
  quantityTotal : number ;
  orderdetials : Detials[] | MatTableDataSource<Detials>;
}
export interface Detials {
  idd : number;
  price :number;
  quantity : number;
  discount : number;
  tax : number;
  total : number;
}
const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [];
@Component({
  selector: 'app-detials-click',
  templateUrl: './detials-click.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./detials-click.component.css']
})
export class DETIALSCLICKComponent implements OnInit {
  displayedColumns: string[] =
  ['id','operationType','date','address','custname',
  'nettotal','grosstotal','totaltax'];
//  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(ELEMENT_DATA);
 dataSource: MatTableDataSource<any[]> = new MatTableDataSource<any[]>([ELEMENT_DATA]);
 @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort = new MatSort;
 @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator!: MatPaginator;
  

  constructor(private api : ApiService,
    private dialog : MatDialog,
    private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.GetAllOrders();
  }
  applyFilter(event: Event) {
    const filterValue = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
  }
  GetAllOrders(){
    this.api.getOrder().subscribe({
      next: res => {
        // console.log(res);
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(res);
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      }, error :(err) => {
        alert("Error while fetching the Orders!!")
      }
    })
}
  
}
```

Comment: pass `orderdetials` as dialog data. and use as table's datasource.

Comment: @paranaaan can you please show me how to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `orderdetials` as dialog data. and use as table's datasource.

This might help you to inspire an idea: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-table-design-8d3q4f?file=src/app/app.component.ts)